# Is it possible to connect an initially not-online profile to the Internet in Rock Band 3 for Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band-3

When I first set up my band in RB3, I didn't have an Internet connection, so I pressed "Not online".  However, I've now managed to get online but can't seem to find any way to change the setting.

Is this possible?  I don't really want to have to create a new band and re-unlock everything I've done so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

Go into your Profile menu, and hit Manage Profiles. There should be a "Register" menu option.